# ERROR: "document.querySelector(...) is null"

Tags: angular, typescript

I get stuck here `setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('true').scrollIntoView());`

I want when in html `[style.border]="detailData.selected ? '2.5px solid #FD8023' : ''"` is true and scrolling will scroll here. But it come out error

> ERROR TypeError: "document.querySelector(...) is null"

Hope anyone can help me, please!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selector is not correct, if it's class use `.true` and if it's id use `#true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not correct selector, it should be as:

**If it's class**

```
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.true').scrollIntoView());
```

**If it's id**

```
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#true').scrollIntoView());
```

You can read more about querySelector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

**Update based on comment**

Better to use template variable and use Angular to find view as:

```
<div #scrollableDiv [id]="detailData.key"></div>
```

**In you component**

```
@ViewChild('scrollableDiv') scrollableDiv: ElementRef;

setTimeout(() => {
  this.scrollableDiv.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But if id in my div like this `[id]="detailData.key"` what should I do.

Comment: @Pravu then you should use template variable, I have updated answer.

Comment: I got error `ERROR TypeError: "_this.scrollableDiv.nativeElement is undefined"`.. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use correct syntax (and recommend to avoid `setTimeout`):

```
document.querySelector(".myclass")
document.querySelector("div")
document.querySelector("#id")
```

Also you have to know, that `scrollIntoView()` method is not fully crossbrowser solution (more then half browsers don't support `smooth` scrolling with this method). More details: https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But if id in my div like this `[id]="detailData.key"` what should I do.